# Warning: Illegal string offset 'link-label'

Tags: php, wordpress

I am receiving this error: Warning: "Illegal string offset 'link-label' in /homepages/37/number/htdocs/clickandbuilds/JSSchwalmPhotography/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3211"

I did not change anything on this code. It happened just now. 
It would be very nice if someone can help me eliminate this error. Thank you!

The error is in line 3211: "$list[ $key ] = $value[ $field ];"

Here is the complete section:

```
function wp_list_pluck( $list, $field, $index_key = null ) {
if ( ! $index_key ) {
    /*
     * This is simple. Could at some point wrap array_column()
     * if we knew we had an array of arrays.
     */
    foreach ( $list as $key => $value ) {
        if ( is_object( $value ) ) {
            $list[ $key ] = $value->$field;
        } else {
            $list[ $key ] = $value[ $field ];
        }
    }
    return $list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the structure of a list while iterating through it is just asking for trouble. Store the results in a different array instead.

```
$new_list = array();
foreach ( $list as $key => $value ) {
  if ( is_object( $value ) ) {
    $new_list[ $key ] = $value->$field;
  } else {
    $new_list[ $key ] = $value[ $field ];
  }
}
return $new_list;
```

**Note:** This will still fail if one or more of the values contained in `$list` is a string variable, but if so, your problem is elsewhere.